# Como comparar um String digitada em JTextField com uma ImageIcon randomizada em um package?

Tags: java, string, random, switch

Ao da um **Random** em um **package** de **ImageIcon** de bandeiras de países como comparar se foi digitado certo o nome da bandeira do país em um **JTextField** pelo usuário?

Para randomizar as imagens das bandeiras eu estou conseguindo assim:

```
File file = new File("src/flagsII");
    String[] imageNames = file.list();
    Random rand = new Random();
```

Uso um botão para randomizar a imagem e outro para comparar, já que não conseguir isso com um único botão.

```
btnFlag.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    // Random
                    int index = rand.nextInt(8);
                    Image im = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/flagsII/" + imageNames[index])).getImage();
                    ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon(im);
                    jlbFlag.setIcon(iconLogo);
                }
            });         
            jContentPane.add(btnFlag);
        }
        return jContentPane;
    }
```

Agora para comparar não estou conseguindo:

```
int score = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Random
        // int flags = (int) (8 * Math.random() + 1);
        // int flags = (int) (Math.random() * 8);
        
        String country = textField.getText().toLowerCase();

        switch (country) {

        case "Australia":
            // jlbFlag.setIcon(new
            // ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(("flags/Australia.png"))));
            if (imageNames.equals(country)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Geography Quiz", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                score = score + 1;
                lblScore.setText("Score: " + score);

            } else {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect!", "Geography Quiz", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                score = score - 1;
                lblScore.setText("Score: " + score);
            }
            break;

        case "Brazil":
            // jlbFlag.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(("flags/Brazil.png"))));
            if (imageNames.equals(country)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Geography Quiz", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                score = score + 1;
                lblScore.setText("Score: " + score);

            } else {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect!", "Geography Quiz", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                score = score - 1;
                lblScore.setText("Score: " + score);
            }
            break;

        case "China":
            // jlbFlag.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(("flags/China
            // (2).png"))));
            if (imageNames.equals(country)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Geography Quiz", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                score = score + 1;
                lblScore.setText("Score: " + score);

            } else {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect!", "Geography Quiz", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                score = score - 1;
                lblScore.setText("Score: " + score);
            }
            break;
default:
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect!", "Geography Quiz", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(imageNames);

    }
```

E para declarar no botão Submit declaro isso:

```
jbtSubmit.addActionListener(this);
```

[image: Screenshots Geography Quiz]

Answer (score 0):

Como está agora, o código compara o texto digitado com a lista de países, o que não faz sentido. Você precisa armazenar o nome do país sorteado num campo, para fazer a comparação quando o usuário pressionar "Submit", assim não seria necessário prever todos os casos (o `switch` poderia ser removido).

Sugiro definir um mapeamento com nomes de países e os respectivos arquivos com as bandeiras (há várias maneiras de se fazer isso), para que o usuário não precise digitar "China (2).jpg" para acertar a questão. Ao sortear o índice, o elemento correspondente do nome é salvo, e a respectiva bandeira é exibida na `JLabel`.